# Displaying portion of file name using command

Tags: linux, windows, bash, batch-file

i have hundreds of file having name in a specific pattern , i want to get portion of filename only for example

like if filenames are  REE_45K.txt  or REE_46B.txt  or REE_21K.txt or REE_229N.txt ot REE9999G.txt
i want to display only 45K 46B ,21K,229N,9999G

if possible please give Linux and windows versions commands

```
findstr _.*.  *.*  i found this command working for windows , can u verify it
```

Comment: Starting from full path or only the filename?

Comment: only the file name @Cheloide

Comment: this works for windows but not always .. 
findstr /s  _.*.  *.* . >a.txt

Comment: Is it always going to be the last three characters of the file name, or is it the bit between the last underscore and the extension?

Comment: @SomethingDark no it is between underscore and dot ,

Answer (score 1):

For bash on linux:

```
#!/bin/bash
filename="REE_45K.txt"
no_ext="${filename%.*}"  # "REE_45K"
echo "${no_ext##*_}"
```

gives `45K`

Comment: thanks , while googling i found this command  grep -h '??.*??' PATH   , can u expain this one if possible

Comment: @user143252 See this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean

Answer (score 0):

For linux bash:

```
for filename in REE_45K.txt  REE_46B.txt  REE_21K.txt
do
  echo $filename |sed  's/REE_\(.*\).txt/\1/g'
done
```

It gives:

```
45K
46B
21K
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you string replace in a windows batch file. 
{var} = %{var}:{find}={relacement}%
Here is an example for you:

```
@echo off
set filename="REE_45K.txt"
echo %filename%
set filename=%filename:REE_=%
set filename=%filename:.txt=%
echo %filename%
```

Output:

```
"REE_45K.txt"
"45K"
```